# Breaker keeps tripping after installing new switch

Tags: electrical

I recently replaced an old light switch on my second floor with a new one.  The light is on a circuit that allows a switch on the main floor to turn on/off the light, as well as the switch I replaced on the second floor (where the light is).  Ever since I put in the new switch, the **old** switch on the main floor trips the breaker whenever it is turned to the on position.  As long as I keep the old switch in the off position the breaker doesn't trip.
This never happened with the old switch upstairs.  I have ensured there are no live wires touching anything in either receptacle box.  I can't figure out what is going on - why would the old switch trip the breaker now, when it never did before?

Comment: Did you take before pictures when removing the wires?  Do they match up with the after pictures?

Comment: You may have miswired and are shorting live to neutral. A 2 way connection with 2 switches is different to wiring a single switch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the breaker a GFCI?

Comment: You've got 3-way switches. In 3-way switches, location of screws can vary between brands/models of switches, so it is not *necessarily* top-left of old goes to top-left of new, etc.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   Do they keep the screw colours or do they change also to confuse(drive us around the bend) us more?

Comment: The screw colors are less important. As in, if the screws are different colors (black, brass, silver) then on any 3-way it *should* be: 2 travelers are one color, 1 common is a different color. So if one company has brass travelers, black common and another has black travelers, silver common, it wouldn't really matter because you are just looking for "2 vs. 1".

Answer (score 1):

**Only Hot Wires Are Switched**

If you mistakenly connected a grounded wire to a switched pole then the breaker will trip.  All of the switched wires at both switches, including the supply, load, and any travelers, are all to be treated as hot wires.  When you have 2 switches for the same light, some of the wires connect between the switches, which means moving a wire in one box could cause a short circuit at the other box.

If you made any other changes to the circuit, such as replacing the light outlet, then there is even more opportunity for mistakes.

**Switches Require Grounding**

With few exceptions, the switch yoke must be grounded, so there are usually more than two wires involved, and they need to be correct.

Depending on the type of switch, a grounded conductor (neutral) might be needed as well.

**As long as I keep the old switch in the off position...**

This is neither safe nor reasonable.  The circuit breaker should be kept in the off position until the switch you installed has been removed.

> This never happened with the old switch upstairs.

The old switch upstairs was installed by a competent laborer who attached the wires correctly.  That's the only difference.

> I have ensured there are no live wires touching anything in either receptacle box.

Nonsense.  I hope my explanation of hot wire switching is helpful, otherwise you will need to find someone to fix those switches.

Comment: Thanks all.  Lots of food for thought.  I thought I had a single pole single switch that I was replacing but the comment about it being a 3 way switch makes sense.  I'll replace what I installed with a new 3 way and see if that works.  The house is a mess in general re wiring  - the builder wired things up weirdly.  I've replaced single lights which had six wires in the junction box from the builder - why? I have no idea; and in some of the boxes they included grounds and in others they didn't  - so everytime I replace something I have to figure what they did ....

Comment: @TollyFoerstner Six wires in a junction box is normal.  That's what junction boxes are for.  You really should consider taking a class or reading a book about home wiring.

Comment: To Robert - I take your point and don't want to get into too many details.  Both my son inlaw and brother inlaw are licensed, red seal electricians and each time they come over to give me a hand they just shake their heads at what the builder did - seems like a lot of hillbilly work was done by the builder according to them. They're both not available right now or I would have asked them to help out - I might just call an electrician in.  I am good at plumbing and carpentry and to be honest, usually try to avoid working with electrical stuff.